# The method nextInt(int) is undefined for the type Random

Tags: java, random, package

I have imported the java.util package but still nextInt, nextBoolean, nextDouble and other functions are not recognisable

```
import java.util.*;

public class Random {

public static void main(String[] args){


    Random random = new Random();
    System.out.println(random.nextInt(10));
    System.out.println(random.nextBoolean());
    System.out.println(random.nextDouble());
    System.out.println(random.nextFloat());
    System.out.println(random.nextGaussian());
    byte[] bytes = new byte[10];
    random.nextBytes(bytes);
    System.out.printf("[");
    for(int i = 0; i< bytes.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%d ", bytes[i]);
    }
    System.out.printf("]\n");

      System.out.println(random.nextLong());  
  System.out.println(random.nextInt());

  long seed = 95;
  random.setSeed(seed);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should change your `Random` class name to something else.

Answer (score 2):

The name of your class is Random.

Change it to anything else:

```
....
public class AnotherName {
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class `Random` shadows `java.util.Random` (your import has lower resolution then the local class name); you can change the local class name or you could use fully qualified class name (which will also remove the need for the `import`). Like,

```
java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();
```